# ruby on rails: right location for sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a general question about rails controllers/models:
I have a model Providers, that represents the table providers in my database.
If I have sql queries (with certain conditions) to gather information from that table, where the SQL code should be implemented, in the model or in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you're doing anything complex, put it in the model.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create named scope with custom SQL in your model, of course.